# Why for different websites are there different TLS message type sequences?

Tags: tls

Observing the TLS message type sequences via Wireshark by navigating different websites, it's found that the sequences are different.

Taking following cases as an example, when comparing Case1 with Case2 and Case3, the traces are different in terms of **NewSessionTicket**, **ServerKeyExchange**, **EncryptedHandShakeMessage**.

Any reason for that? Is this due to the different TLS implementations?

Case1:

> ClientHello,  **ServerHello,  Certificate,    ServerKeyExchange,  ServerHelloDone,**  ClientKeyExchange,  ChangeCipherSpec,   EncryptedHandshakeMessage,  **NewSessionTicket**,   ChangeCipherSpec,   EncryptedHandshakeMessage, ApplicationData*4

Case2

> ClientHello, ServerHello, Certificate, ServerKeyExchange, ServerHelloDone, ClientKeyExchange, **ChangeCipherSpec, EncryptedHandshakeMessage,  ChangeCipherSpec,   EncryptedHandshakeMessage**, ApplicationData*2

Case3

> ClientHello, **ServerHello, Certificate, ServerHelloDone,** ClientKeyExchange, ChangeCipherSpec, EncryptedHandshakeMessage,   ChangeCipherSpect,  EncryptedHandshakeMessage,  ApplicationData*8

Comment: The problem is that you treat `MultipleHandshakeMessage` as a message by its own - which it is not. Look instead at the actual messages "contained" in this `MultipleHandshakeMessage`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I don't think this duplicate question for three reasons: 1) The same setting is used, only case2 has `multipleHandshakeMessage`, 2) besides, the two traces are also different in `EncryptedHandshakeMessage` and `new session tickets`. 3) trace differece also been noticed for some other cases, above are just two examples, so it's not just `MultipleHandshakeMessage` quesstion.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, could you please help to reopen this question if you think the justification is clear to you. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your comments I don't think that you have understood the answer to the previous question even though you've accepted the answer. `MultipleHandshakeMessage` is no real TLS message but just means that there are multiple TLS messages in the same TCP packet. You'll find the `ServerHello` etc you are missing if you look at the details for the `MultipleHandshakeMessage`. I don't see any need to reopen this question as it is now. It might be worth reopening if you expand the `MultipleHandshakeMessage` and detail exactly which differences between the handshakes worry you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, you're right. I've added more cases and details in other differences. Please let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Please replace all `MultipleHandshakeMessage` with the real messages in order to make a useful comparison possible. And, I have the feeling that you don't have enough understanding of how a TLS handshake works in the first place and what all these different message types are actually used for. It is hard to explain the differences between handshakes if you don't even know what the messages are for.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It has been revised to make the question clearer.

Comment: Did not really help. For once, it seems to be incomplete since there is no ServerHelloDone in  case 2. Then it is confusing since it not clear which of these messages are from client to server and which from server to client. And again, it looks like you don't understand what the different messages mean in the first place so it is hard to explain the differences.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. The ServerHelloDone was missed in case2 and added in the current revised version. I'm still new in this area and I've learned the different message meanings. For this question, I'm really want to know whether the existence of the difference in the messages is due to the different functionality/security requirement of the websites.

Comment: In short: it is due to different ciphers used (ServerKeyExchange is used with DHE/ECDHE but not RSA key exchange) and enabled or disabled support for session reuse using tickets (NewSessionTicket). Differences might be due to different implementations but also different configurations of the TLS stack. As for EncryptedHandShakeMessage - This is likely the Finished message (first encrypted) and I don't see any relevant differences regarding this message.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thanks very much for the hint. I'll read more according to your answer.